# want to add done button in keyboard controls to hide keyboard in ios

Tags: ios, appium-ios

I want to hide the keyboard after entering data in the fields. For the situation when there is return button in device keyboard the below code works fine.

```
IOSDriver< WebElement> AD= (IOSDriver) driver;
AD.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

But when there is a done button it doesn't. I suppose we have to add this button.

Answer (score 1):

From java-client's IOSDriver class: http://appium.github.io/java-client/

```
public void hideKeyboard(String strategy, String keyName)

Description copied from interface: IOSDeviceActionShortcuts
Hides the keyboard if it is showing. Available strategies are PRESS_KEY and TAP_OUTSIDE. One taps outside the keyboard, the other presses a key of your choosing (probably the 'Done' key). Hiding the keyboard often depends on the way an app is implemented, no single strategy always works.
```

So you'll need to use the following command to press Done on the keyboard:
`AD.hideKeyboard("PRESS_KEY", "Done");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work after entering click on Done

> ((IOSDriver)driver).findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='Done']")).click();